# Safe system call with multiple commands with perl

Tags: perl, input, system, sanitization

I have a Perl script that reads some information from a web form. In order to do proper sanitation, I want to use the `system` syntax described [here](http://www.cgisecurity.com/lib/sips.html).

They suggest that you should form system commands in the following form `system ("cat", "/usr/stats/$username");` so that the username variable would only get interpreted as a argument to cat.

If I had a command that had the form of `system("export REPLYTO=\"$from\"; echo \"$body\" | mail -s \"$subject\"");` which has multiple system commands, how can I properly sanitize the system call?

Comment: I would use [IPC::Run](http://search.cpan.org/~toddr/IPC-Run-0.92/lib/IPC/Run.pm) for this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before I start, note that you can do the `export` in Perl by setting `$ENV{REPLY_TO}`.

---

### Option 1.

You can use [String::ShellQuote](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?String%3a%3aShellQuote)'s `shell_quote`.

```
use autodie qw( :all );
my $cmd = shell_quote('echo', $body) .
    '|' . shell_quote('mail', '-s', $subject);
local $ENV{REPLY_TO} = $from;
system($cmd);
```

### Option 2.

Pass everything by env var.

```
use autodie qw( :all );
local $ENV{REPLY_TO} = $from;
local $ENV{SUBJECT}  = $subject;
local $ENV{BODY}     = $body;
system('echo "$BODY" | mail -s "$SUBJECT"');
```

### Option 3.

Get rid of `echo`

```
use autodie qw( :all );
local $ENV{REPLY_TO} = $from;
open(my $pipe, '|-', 'mail', '-s', $subject);
print($pipe $body);
close($pipe);
die "Child died from signal ".($? & 0x7F)."\n" if $? & 0x7F;
die "Child exited from error ".($? >> 8)."\n" if $? >> 8;
```